# size limit for document.write()

Tags: javascript, document.write

Is there a size limit for document.write() as I am trying to write a large content in an html page using document.write().

Comment: Obvious question: why not use `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement(...));`, append to `document.body.innerHTML`, or (eek) use several `document.write()`s  instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is no size limit on that you can write long data using it.........

Comment: I have tried to inject a HTML Page inside a javascript like Window.document.write(html);  html is the "html code" and finally html form is submitted as below:</form><script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(\"id\").submit();}, 0);</script></body></html>"

Comment: @suki - not getting you at all can you put he text in the question by editing it .......

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only limitation for the document.write() is the string length that you use (which depends on the browser used). However, a single string in any modern browser got practically no limits due to the new techniques of memory management.